# Confused about core data one-to-many configuration

Tags: swift, core-data

Essentially I am creating an app that tracks packages - 1 tracking number to many - detailed updates for that tracking number.

**For example:**

**Parent:** *Tracking #: 102391249*

**Tracking Updates:**

**Child1:** Departed Location

**Child2:** At Local Fedex Facility

**Child3:** Delivered

The following is my current setup, the image on the left being the parent and right being the child:

Was this setup correctly? I am new to CoreData but coming from my knowledge of relational databases I am trying to make sure the id in the parent in the trackingid of the child to create the connection between the 2 "tables"

[image]

Comment: What is the relationship type for each relationship: To One or To Many? Shouldn't the name of the `numbers` relationship be `number` since each tracking update is associated with one tracking number? With a To One relationship, you don't need the `trackingid` attribute in the Details entity. You can use the `trackingnumber` attribute from the relationship as the tracking number for each tracking update.

Comment: @SwiftDevJournal Apologies, having some trouble setting this up. The relationship is one to many... I'm alright with having the user enter the same tracking # twice in the parent table twice (sometimes there could be the same tracking # just different name) Because of this I have the UUID in the parent.

Comment: Can you please elaborate I what I need to do? I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Set the one to many relationship between the Numbers and Details entities to connect the two entities. When you create an instance of the Details entity in your code, set its relationship to a Numbers entity.

```
child.numbers = parent
```

Where `child` is an instance of the Details entity and `parent` is an instance of the Numbers entity.

The `numbers` (changing the name to `number` would be clearer) relationship that you have in the Details entity gives you access to the tracking number. You can access the tracking number using the relationship and the Numbers entity's `tracking number` attribute.

```
let trackingNumber = child.numbers.trackingnumber
```

Since you have access to the tracking number from the relationship, you can remove the `trackingid` attribute from the Details entity.

By the way consider using clearer entity names than Numbers and Details. Your app deals with tracking shipping updates to packages. I recommend renaming Numbers to Package and Details to TrackingUpdates or ShippingDetails.